# Change eagerloaded array keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eager-loading

I've got several `eager loaded` relations in `Laravel 5.6`. I would like to change the array key name to a property on the eager loaded object.

So let's say I have eager loaded this:
[image]

How do I make sure that array key `0` and `1` become the name property ("`COSTS`" and "`SAIL_BOAT_FRIENDLY`") ?

Is that even possible?

-- EDIT

```
return Port::filter($filters)
            ->with('scores')
            ->actives()
            ->paginate(14);
```

**Scores relation**

```
public function scores()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Score::class)
        ->select("id", "port_id", "name", DB::raw('AVG(score) as score'))
        ->groupBy('port_id', 'name');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`keyBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-keyby):

```
$ports = Port::filter($filters)
        ->with('scores')
        ->actives()
        ->paginate(14);

foreach($ports as $port) {
    $port->setRelation('scores', $port->scores->keyBy('name'));
}
```